# GWT Drag And Drop TreeItem

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I'm working to create a Tree where users can move TreeItems by dragging and dropping one TreeItem onto another, using the [gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) library.  I've read that I should set a widget for each TreeItem and make that widget draggable and a dropTarget.  So far I haven't had any success on even just dragging a TreeItem.  I also get a 'draganddrop unhandled exception'.  Am I at least headed in the correct direction, or is there a better way to do this?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
// Create the boundary panel
AbsolutePanel main = new AbsolutePanel();
main.setSize("500px", "500px");
// Create Tree and tree root
Tree tree = new Tree();
TreeItem root = new TreeItem();
root.setText("root");
// Create Label widget and construct treeItem from Label
Label itemLabel = new Label("item1");
TreeItem item = new TreeItem(itemLabel);
// Create DragController for the main panel, and make the Label widget draggable
PickupDragController dragController = new PickupDragController(main, true);
dragController.makeDraggable(item.getWidget());
// Add everything to root panel
root.addItem(item);
tree.addItem(root);
main.add(tree);
RootPanel.get().add(main);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the Getting started guide [here](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/wiki/GettingStarted).

Look at the **How to add drag-and-drop functionality to your project**

What you are missing is a Drop Area. There are classes that implement drop controllers and you should use them. There is no point in having dragabble items that have no place to drop off on.

You can also override some of the functionality of the dnd by implementing logic on events (OnDropStart etc)

Important!!! Don't forget to register the DropController to the PickupDragController.

Here is an example from the dnd site

```
public AbsolutePositionExample(PickupDragController dragController) {
    super(dragController);
    addStyleName(CSS_DEMO_ABSOLUTE_POSITION_EXAMPLE);

    // use the drop target as this composite's widget
    AbsolutePanel positioningDropTarget = new AbsolutePanel();
    positioningDropTarget.setPixelSize(400, 200);
    setWidget(positioningDropTarget);

    // instantiate our drop controller
    absolutePositionDropController = new AbsolutePositionDropController(positioningDropTarget);
    dragController.registerDropController(absolutePositionDropController);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use [gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/). Just wrap the `TreeItem` content with a `FocusPanel` and use its drag event handlers. Using your example:

```
Tree tree = new Tree();
TreeItem root = new TreeItem();
root.setText("root");

Label itemLabel = new Label("item1");
FocusPanel wrapper = new FocusPanel(itemLabel);
TreeItem item = new TreeItem(wrapper);

wrapper.getElement().setDraggable(Element.DRAGGABLE_TRUE);

wrapper.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
        GWT.log("Drag START!");
    }
});

wrapper.addDragEndHandler(new DragEndHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDragEnd(DragEndEvent event) {
        GWT.log("Drag END!");
    }
});

wrapper.addDragOverHandler(new DragOverHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {}
});

wrapper.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
        GWT.log("DROP!");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

root.addItem(item);
tree.addItem(root);
```